# Groovy and Grails application development configuration

Tags: grails

I have to create new application based on Groovy and Grails, versions are-

**grails-2.3.6**

**groovy-2.1.9**

For this what configuration is most suitable please help me...

**GGTS, STS or Eclipse**

**java6, java7 or java8**

I tried everything but no one combination is smooth and flawless for me. I got lots of error in each combination which I tried like

> I tried these sets-
>
> GGTS 3.5.1 and java7,java6
>
> STS and java7,java6
>
> Eclipse juno and java7,java6

I am new to this platform please help me out. thanks.. :)

Comment: First of all you may try to start from console and standalone grails which contains inside the correct version of groovy. `grails create-app`. This must work with any JDK version

Comment: After that you may try to import that project to grails.
And please write all your errors here. All our telepaths are in vacations now.

Comment: @wwarlock ..thanks so much for your quick response, I am totally new to this and tried to do with console also, but now I have to move on TOOL and Real Application so please give your suggestions about perfect combination.

Comment: You can run grails 2.X with java6 and java7, looks like problem in you r datasource configuration and table mapping. please cross check it.

Comment: No database mapping in my application. Sample program is giving such problem.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm using Debian, Grails 2.3.6 and Java 7. Works fine for me. Seems like the "perfect" combination. Can you try 2.3.6 with Java 7 and post here what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Currently I am using windows 8 64bit... Actually I am asking that which is suitable combination for Grails application development.

Comment: https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/ Grails and Groovy versions seems fine. I used STS and Intellij fro Grails2.x development and used also Java 7 and 8 for them (however only linux distros). It seems that the problem is in your custom env configuration.